# Content Label warning for Flutter app while publishing app to google play

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to publish a Flutter app on Google Playstore, but in the pre-launch reports, I keep getting a `Content Labelling` warning. Something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to deal with this warning?

Comment: I get the same issue - also found no solution

Comment: I think it might be fixed by adding Semantics widget to places, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Semantics-class.html . I might be wrong though, also I am not going to test this hypothesis any time soon :/

Comment: any conclusions? @aleskva

Comment: Any fix for this warning ?

Comment: Semantics did not help in this case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I would just ignore it. I have many accessibility warnings in my app, all involving images used as icons or decorations for dialogues. These images cannot be easily described so that a visually impaired person can hear the description. I have therefore not attempted to fix the warning. Your app will still be accepted, despite this.

Answer (score 0):

We should use Semantics widget. As described in this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvtMt_DtFrQ).